# Загрузка файла на сервер и загрузка файла с сервера(net core web api)

Tags: .net, core, webapi

Застрял на реализации загрузки файла на сервер и выгрузке в построении логики. Есть apk, который нужно закинуть на сервер. Кто может подсказать, какая будет реализация в коде?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код лучше вставлять не картинкой, а текстом, так и поиск будет работать и читать/копировать лучше.

Comment: `IFormFile` это и есть ваш файл (stream), как и любой другой поток вы можете его сохранить куда угодно. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322085/how-to-save-iformfile-to-disk

Comment: блин, в контроллере знаю как примерно реализовать, а в logic чет туплю. Обновление версии apk реализовал по id
Загрузку файла на сервер знаю что надо сначать указать путь к файлу, проверить и потом грузить, а выгрузку нахожу путь и оттуда уже стягиваю. Только вот как это все в коде написать